# UWP: DependencyProperty with DefaultValue ThemeResource

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, dependency-properties

I have a custom UIElement with a `FontIcon` as body.

This `FontIcon` has a `Foreground` property that I want to bind to a `DependencyProperty`.

The `DependencyProperty` is declared as follows:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "ForegroundColor", typeof( Brush ),
                                                                  typeof( ColorableCheckbox ),
                                                                  new PropertyMetadata( null, null ) );

public Brush ForegroundColor
  {
     get { return (Brush)GetValue( ForegroundColorProperty ); }
     set { SetValue( ForegroundColorProperty, value ); }
  }
```

In my declaration the `defaultValue` of the `PropertyMetadata` is null, I want this to be the value of a `ThemeResource`.

Sadly using

```
<FontIcon x:Name="Glyph"
          FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
          Glyph="&#xE001;"
          FontSize="20"
          Foreground="{Binding Path=ForegroundColor,FallbackValue={ThemeResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}}" />
```

doesn't work, it gives an error:

```
{DynamicResource} can only be used with dependency property
```

How can I set the default value to the `ThemeResource`? Either in code-behind with the `PropertyMetadata` or in XAML?

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33356217/setting-or-modifying-themeresource-in-code/54156290

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you call a method to set the foreground of "Glyph" in the property changed callback in PropertyMetadata.

So something like this..

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ForegroundColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(ColorableCheckbox), new PropertyMetadata(null, UpdateForeground));

private static void UpdateForeground(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
    var ctrl = (ColorableCheckbox) obj;
    var brush = args.NewValue as Brush;

    if (brush == null)
        return;

    ctrl.Glyph.Foreground = brush;
}
```

Or in XAML give your user control a name and set that as the source to the binding.

e.g.

```
<UserControl x:Name="ColorCheckbox"...>
   <FontIcon x:Name="Glyph"
          FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"
          Glyph="&#xE001;"
          FontSize="20"
          Foreground="{Binding ForegroundColor,FallbackValue={StaticResource SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush}, ElementName=ColorCheckbox}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Glyph wouldn't be available in the static context. It also feels hacky to set the Glyph's `Foreground` property manually in code-behind.

Comment: And added a possible XAML only solution

Comment: Your XAML solution is almost exactly the same as the one I posted in the original question, and I already stated it doesn't work. (Your difference is that you omitted `Path=` and added `, ElementName=ColorCheckbox}`)

Comment: Try using StaticResource instead of ThemeResource. If you still want it to be dynamic instead of static you'll have to create a property in the code behind of the control that returns the ThemeResource value and bind FallbackValue to that. The ElementName is necessary here since you're binding to a property of the control. If not it will try to bind to the DataContext of the control.

Comment: If that really is the only way (needs code), then the following solution would be better: `public static readonly DependencyProperty ForegroundColorProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "ForegroundColor", typeof( Brush ),
                                                                  typeof( ColorableCheckbox ),
                                                                  PropertyMetadata.Create( () => Application.Current.Resources["SystemControlHighlightAltChromeWhiteBrush"] ) );`

Comment: Yes you could do that too. But if your app isn't going to switch themes while it's running you can use StaticResource instead.

Comment: It can switch themes while it's running, who knows the crazy kind of things people do while your app is running. (Imagine using something like `SystemControlForegroundAccentBrush` instead, it can change while the user is running your app). I want this solution to be as global as possible.